# download packages for offline gentoo update

Tags: gentoo, emerge, portage

I have a machine with gentoo that does not have internet access but I want to install a few packages on it. I do not have another machine with gentoo, how does one download packages for it? google tells me you use emerge to download on one machine and emerge to install on the other, but as I've said, I have a single gentoo machine, how does one download packages with another os (windows or ubuntu)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could replace the download command with one that just logs the urls instead *), then run `emerge --fetchonly <other arguments>`, collect the urls and download them on another machine, transfer the files back to the gentoo machine to the correct directory and then `emerge <other arguments>` to install..

*) by e.g. configuring `FETCHCOMMAND` in e.g. `/etc/portage/make.conf`

Let me know if you need further help accomplishing this.

Answer (score 0):

Look inside the `ebuild` file, and there you will see a line starting with `SRC_URI`, e.g. for `bzip2`: https://gitweb.gentoo.org/repo/gentoo.git/tree/app-arch/bzip2/bzip2-1.0.7.ebuild#n13

This line has the files wich `emerge` would download.

You can download all the files from any mirror (http://www.gentoo.org/main/en/mirrors.xml), just look into the distfiles directory.